# Android developement : Emulator skin and resolution

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have just started development in Android... and I have searched a lot for the answer to the question below. It seems a very basic thing which I cannot figure out.

I am using eclipse Juno, APK17 on Windows server 2007 . When I try out the emulator I do not see the options to change the size or resolution as I have seen in many articles ([example](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html)) Instead the only option available for me is "skin : Display a skin with hardware controls ". Under "Start", i can set the resolution but the settings are lost once I run the application. How can I get the emulator to show the skin and resolution as shown in the example? Is it an option available on Eclipse on Windows?

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure that I have correctly understood your problem. Are you using the Android Virtual Device Manager? When you create a new emulated device (by clicking on 'new'), what option do you see ? Looks like your configuring AVD instead of a device.

Comment: Yes, am using AVD manager. When i click on new i get the options to add Device, Target, Keyboard (hardware keyboard present), skin (Display a skin with hardware controls), Front camera, Back camera, Memory Options, Internal Storage, SD Card...

Comment: Okay. Actually, the AVD has recently changed, now you can't choose the 'exact' resolution, but in 'device' you can pick the one you want (for example 'Nexus 4 (4.7", 768x1280, xhdpi)'. This only affect screen and resolution. I think that's the only way to choose the resolution and the size since the update, but i'm not 100% sure.